# Intersection of a exponential and a sin wave

Tags: functions, trigonometry, exponential-function

I need to find the intersection between to functions to alter the domain so that they connect at said intersection.

$$0.01^{x-17.7}+7 = \sin\left(\frac {x}{1.3} + 2.6\right) + 8$$

This is for a year 12 mathematics assessment where I have to design a pool using functions. I sketched the graph to begin with in Desmos using estimated intersections but I need to find the actual intersection using mathematics. I'm not sure if this is possible using normal methods but it would be greatly appreciated if anyone could help me out. (sorry the equation doesn't look nice I'm not sure how to work the formatting)

Comment: Please use the [basic tutorial and quick reference guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to ensure your mathjax formatting is correct.

Comment: Assume $x > 0$.  The left side is greater than 7;  the right greater has minimum 7.  So a brief inspection suggests that there are infinite solutions for $x > 18$ paired either side of where $\sin(x/1.3+2.6) = -1$.  Otherwise, there is one solution for $x < 18$.  It seems likely you can only find numerical approximations.  Newton's method applied to any one of the possible points should be able to deliver whatever level of accuracy needed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of thinking about equations, it is *often* better to think about the zero'ss of a function.

Prefering to work with whole numbers and simplifying what in written in the post, let us consider the function
$$f(x)=10^{\frac{177}{5}-2 x}- \left(1+\sin \left(\frac{10 }{13}x+\frac{13}{5}\right)\right)$$

The quantity in parentheses is bounded by $2$. So, we need to explore around $x$ such that
$$10^{\frac{177}{5}-2 x}=2 \implies x=\frac{177}{10}-\frac{\log (2)}{2 \log (10)}\sim 17.5495$$

$f(x)$ varies so fast and produces so large numbers that it is better to consider instead
$$g(x)=\log \left(10^{\frac{177}{5}-2 x}\right)-\log\left(1+\sin \left(\frac{10 }{13}x+\frac{13}{5}\right)\right)$$ which, more or less, looks like a strainght line.

To have an *estimate* of the solution, make a series expansion around $x=\frac {177}{10}$. This write
$$g(x)=-\log \left(1+\sin
   \left(\frac{1054}{65}\right)\right)+\left(x-\frac{177}{10}\right) \left(-\log
   (100)-\frac{10 \cos \left(\frac{1054}{65}\right)}{13 \left(1+\sin
   \left(\frac{1054}{65}\right)\right)}\right)+O\left(\left(x-\frac{177}{10}\right)
   ^2\right)$$ Neglecting the higher order terms, the solution of the linear equation is then
$$x=\frac {177}{10}-\frac{13 \left(1+\sin \left(\frac{1054}{65}\right)\right) \log \left(1+\sin
   \left(\frac{1054}{65}\right)\right)}{10 \cos \left(\frac{1054}{65}\right)+26
   \log (10) \left(1+\sin \left(\frac{1054}{65}\right)\right)}$$ which is $x\sim 17.9018$ while the "exact" solution is $17.9103$.

I suppose that this is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Solving your equation is the same as founding the zeros of the function
$$f(x)=0.01^{x-17.7}- \sin\left(\frac {x}{1.3} + 2.6\right) - 1$$
You have already used desmos to estimate a root around $x_0=17$

Thus you can use Newton method setting

$x_0=17$

$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)};\;n>0$

where $f'(x)=-4.60517 \cdot0.01^{x-17.7}-0.769231 \cos (0.769231 x+2.6)$

after some steps you get $x^*\approx 17.91$

There is another solution around $x_0=19$

repeat the procedure until you find $x^{**}\approx 18.9875$$

There are infinitely many because $\sin\left(\frac {x}{1.3} + 2.6\right) + 1$ is periodic and oscillates between $0$ and $2$ and exponential tend to zero when $x\to\infty$.